# Distinguishing overriding and overloading

Tags: python

I have two classes in python

1. Drunk
2. Usual Drunk

The usual drunk class inherits from the drunk and provides a new implementation for its move method as shown below

```
class Drunk:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def move(self,field,cp,dist=1):
        if field.getDrunk().name!= self.name:
            raise ValueError('Drunk not in the field!')
        for i in range(dist):   
            #pt = CompassPt(random.choice(CompassPt.possibles))
            field.move(cp,1)


class UsualDrunk(Drunk):
    def move(self,field,dist=1):
        cp = random.choice(CompassPt.possibles)
        Drunk.move(self,field,CompassPt(cp),dist)
```

Now the usual drunk class has two methods named move but with different parameters.

So in this scenario is it overriding or overloading?

Comment: if your in 2.6 you should inherent from object in drunk..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's overriding. Python does not support overloading.

That said, overriding a method with one that accepts different arguments, especially when it accepts *fewer* arguments than the base class method, is a Bad Idea. Consider:

```
some_drunk.move(field, cp)
```

If `some_drunk` is a regular `Drunk`, this works. But if it's a `UsualDrunk`, it'll pass the value of `cp` to the `dist` parameter, which is probably not what was intended.

Comment: That's it. Something like this in java for example would be overloading, as the `UsualDrunk` class would have 2 implementations of move depending on which parameters you pass to it, but in python that's not possible

Comment: So does that mean that python is not 100% object oriented or all these things are happening somewhere under the hood?

Comment: Right, python supports OOP, but it's not 100% object-oriented, quoting the wikipedia: `Python supports multiple programming paradigms, primarily but not limited to object oriented, imperative and, to a lesser extent, functional programming styles.`

Comment: @maid450 @user567797: Python is perfectly object-oriented. Overloading is not really connected to OOP, even though it's commonly found in static OO languages. Overloading is not included (at language level - you can do this dynamically yourself) because it's impossible to do statically in a dynamic language.

Comment: when I say that it's not 100% object oriented I mean it's not purely object-oriented as you can write a whole script without a single class

Comment: @maid450: no you can't, Python just provides you with the convincing illusion that you can by dispensing with all the unnecessary boilerplate languages like Java impose.

Comment: @ncoghlan: Where did you get the idea that "you can't [write a whole script without a single class]" ?

Comment: Because modules are themselves instances of the module class, and absolutely everything else in Python (from integers on up) is also a full fledged class. Python lets you program in other ways, but that doesn't make it less than 100% object oriented.

Comment: Cool debate. We should blog this somewhere. :)